# Failing to install awswrangler or pyarrow due to an issue with CMake

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cmake, pyarrow

I am getting this error while running pip install awswrangler

```
-- Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package):
        Found package configuration file:
      
          /opt/homebrew/lib/cmake/Arrow/ArrowConfig.cmake
      
        but it set Arrow_FOUND to FALSE so package "Arrow" is considered to be NOT
        FOUND.  Reason given by package:
      
        Arrow could not be found because dependency ProtobufAlt could not be found.
      
      
      
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      error: command '/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried installing pyarrow first, but it is failing with the same step. I don't know what directory to give as environmental variable as I could not install pyarrow.

Comment: It looks like pyarrow doesn't have wheels for your environment. it would mean you have to install pyarrow from source (instead of from pre compiled binary). Instructions can be found here https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#installing-from-source (but it's not easy)